# Installed Module crash my site. How do I bring my site back up by uninstalling a module

Tags: installation

I installed a module but it crashed my site and I can't get to the administrator backend anymore.  How do I disable this module to bring the site back up?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What module? Any error messages? How did you install it? Do you have access to the command line? Drush? Please edit your question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, try to removing the module from your module folder and run http://YOURSITENAME/update.php

or

[Removing module via Database](http://www.foxwebdevelopment.com/blog/disable-module-via-database-in-drupal-8) - In Drupal 8 it is a bit hard to remove a module.

I think the best way is to use Drush.

```
drush pm-uninstall module-name (machine-name)
```